# How to place one card a little higher then its neighbor in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a card a little above then its neighbor column. Here is an image of those cards placement:

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<div class="row">

                    <div class="col span-1-of-2 service-cards card-set">

                        <div class="card first-card">
                            <div class="container">
                                <img src="resources/img/restaurant-light@2x.png" class="icon-small">
                                <h4><b>UI/UX & mobile <br>application</b></h4> 
                                <p class="subtitle-paragraph service-para-1">We are the finest digital solution providers in town with high quality service.</p> 
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="container">
                                <img src="resources/img/restaurant-light@2x.png" class="icon-small">
                                <h4><b>Branding & <br>Corporate identity</b></h4> 
                                <p class="subtitle-paragraph service-para">We are the finest digital solution providers in town with high quality service.</p> 
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: `margin-top` doesn't work?

Comment: no it does not both of them gets the margin

Comment: You can give an id to the first, then you give the margin just for it

Comment: can you show us your css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use relative position to place one card little lower than the other card

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  height: 170px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.first-card {
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card first-card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS only on your `card first-card` you can give it unique properties. Either try what the comments are suggesting and use `margin-top` or play around with different positioning types. For example `position: absolute; top: 20px;` etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
.first-card {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%
}
```

set the card relative to itself and move it down whatever amount you want from its original position in the document flow.

Answer (score 0):

Its looking very simple thing ..but without knowing your css this is just what i can suggest
You can use something like also works

```
.card.first-card .container { 
margin-top:40px;
}
```

or

```
.card-set {
  display:flex;
}
.card.first-card {
  margin-top:40px;
}
```